# Differentiation of residual sum-of-squares

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vector-spaces

In a Book(The Elements of statistical learning), I see the below equation $(2)$ is derived from $(1)$ by differentiation.
$$\begin{align}
RSS(\beta) & = (y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta) & (1)\\
\frac{dRSS}{d\beta} & = -2X^T(y-X\beta) & (2)\\
\frac{d^2RSS}{d\beta d\beta^T} & = 2X^TX & (3) 
\end{align}$$

I tried to derive $(2)$ from $(1)$ like below. What's wrong with my derivation?

$$\begin{align}
RSS(\beta)& = (y-X\beta)^T(y-X\beta) & (4)\\
& = (y^T-\beta^TX^T)(y-X\beta) & (5)\\
& = y^Ty - y^TX\beta - \beta^TX^Ty + \beta^TX^TX\beta & (6)\\
\frac{dRSS}{d\beta} & = -y^TX + \beta^TX^TX & (7)\\
\frac{d^2RSS}{d\beta d\beta^T} & = X^TX & (8) 
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 0):

$β$ and $β^T$ contain the same variables, so both must be considered in a partial derivative for the variables $β_k$. Also note that, for real vectors and matrices, the transpose of a scalar quantity is the same quantity, and thus
$$
y^TXβ=β^TX^Ty
$$
If you want it more algebraic, replace $β$ with $β+Δβ$ in the original formula and find the combined coefficient of all terms linear in $Δβ$.

Comment: Thank you! I understand now.